# convert sess.run to pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch

I am trying to convert a code from tf to pytorch.
The part of the code where I am stuck is this sess.run.  As fas as I know, pytorch doesn't need it, but I don't find the way to replicate it. I attach you the code.

TF:

```
ebnos_db = np.linspace(1,6, 6)
bers_no_training = np.zeros(shape=[ebnos_db.shape[0]])
for j in range(epochs):
    for i in range(ebnos_db.shape[0]):
        ebno_db = ebnos_db[i]
        bers_no_training[i] += sess.run(ber, feed_dict={
            batch_size: samples,
            noise_var: ebnodb2noisevar(ebno_db, coderate)
        })
bers_no_training /= epochs
```

samples is a int32 and ebnodb2noisevar() returns a float32.

BER in TF is calculated as:

```
ber = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.not_equal(x, x_hat), dtype=tf.float32))
```

and in PT:

```
wrong_bits = ( torch.eq(x, x_hat).type(torch.float32) * -1 ) + 1
ber = torch.mean(wrong_bits)
```

I think BER is well computed, but the main problem is that I don't know how to convert sess.run into PyTorch, nor I completely understand its function.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same in PyTorch but easier when it comes to `ber`:

```
ber = torch.mean((x != x_hat).float())
```

would be enough.

Yes, PyTorch doesn't need it as it's based on dynamic graph construction (unlike Tensorflow with it's static approach).

In `tensorflow` `sess.run` is used to feed values into created graph; here `tf.Placeholder` (variable in graph which represents a node where a user can "inject" his data) named `batch_size` will be fed with `samples` and `noise_var` with `ebnodb2noisevar(ebno_db, coderate)`.

Translating this to PyTorch is usually straightforward as you don't need any graph-like approaches with session. Just use your neural network (or a-like) with correct input (like `samples` and `noise_var`) and you are fine. You have to check your graph (so how `ber` is constructed from `batch_size` and `noise_var`) and reimplement it in PyTorch.

Also, please check [PyTorch introductory tutorials](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html) to get a feel of the framework before diving into it.